# Run MySQL query from external script with Slim Framework

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am using Slim Framework to create REST API. 
There is also table in my mysql db where I store information about each request to server.

I have separate file called functions.php where I have log_request() function

```
require_once('dbconnect.php');
function log_request() {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = "INSERT INTO log_table (....) VALUES (...) ";
    $mysqli->query($query); 
}
```

If I run this script - new record is added to my table. But when I run it using Slim

```
$app->get('/api/something', function($request, $response) {
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    include_once('functions.php');

    log_request();
});
```

I am receiving this error

> Call to a member function query() on null

So $mysqli inside log_request() is null - why does it happen?

Comment: connection not working !!!

Comment: Since the file `functions.php` already includes `dbconnect.php`, there's no need to include that file in your controller function as well. In general, I would recommend creating a db-class (or use any of the excellent db-abstraction libraries that already exists) instead.

Comment: if i comment require_once('dbconnect.php'); line in my Slim code - I have the same error. I also need dbconnect.php script in Slim code.  Can you provide any example of such abstraction as an answer?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Scriptonomy - in order to use MySQL or to prepare, manage, and inject application dependencies we should use dependency container.

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/di.html

**Step 1**

create dependencies.php file

```
// DIC configuration
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $host    = "localhost";
    $user    = "user";
    $pass    = "password";
    $db_name = "database_name";
    $mysqli  = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    return $mysqli;
};
```

**Step 2**

add this code before $app->run();

```
// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
```

**Step 3**

Now you can use mysql (or any other injection)

```
$app->post('foo', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $res = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `app_jobs`");
    .......
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$mysqli;` is not in global scoped. You are employing bad practices all across. Refactor your code to take advantage of the advanced Slim PHP features such as [Dependency Container](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html) or Dependency Injection.

By including the `dbconnect` file inside another function you have effectively scoped its variables to that block scope. You could simply remove the `global` keyword and the code should work.

Comment: If i delete global $mysqli; from function code - it still not working